# MAGENTO Catalog-Product-Custom Options Adding a custom option

Tags: php, magento

I am very new to magento and I want to add a custom option to the Custom Options as described in the title. I think that I am already in the right file wich is : app->design->adminhtml->default->default->template->catalog->product->edit->opt‌​ions->option.phtml So now is my question, how do I add custom options in there so I can select some of my own code.
For further declaration i'll add a screen shot that might help explain what I mean to do.
http://prntscr.com/38nk5b I have to insert it like this because I don't have enough reputation yet to post a picture. Apoligy for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add custom options from `Magento admin.`

Goto `Admin->catalog->Manage Products`

click on any products. In the left navigation at the bottom there is `custom options` tab.

`Add custom options from there for each product.`

OR

```
$option = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_option');
                $option->setProduct($product);

                $values = array(
                      //data here
                        );


                $product->setHasOptions(1); //Hope you can get the $product
                $option->addOption($values);
                $option->saveOptions();
                $product->addOption($option);
```

check this http://pravams.com/2011/05/25/magento-create-custom-options-dynamically/

Comment: I know about that but those options are not custom they are premade and you can select the one you like for that product but I need to insert my own option wich is a piece of code I've been working on lately and not just a premade option.

Comment: Uuhm I do not know what you mean with that exactly :$ but I want to be able to ad a custom option. Now you can select from Radio buttons, Drop-down, checkbox etc, etc. I want my own option in there if you can understand what i mean. My appoligy if I am being obsecure.